# How to pass PHP template through shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to create an overview of my latest blog posts and display this information on a certain part of my homepage. My WordPress theme already has a PHP template in the desired format, which means I would not have to create the actual design/style myself.

As I want this information to be shown in one particular part, I was thinking about creating a shortcode which inserts the information then. I have created shortcodes in WP before, however they always populated simple information.

I am running into the problem now that I do not quite know how I can populate a PHP template via a shortcdode. Before the shortcode function was like similar to this one:

```
function display_my_shortcode($atts, $content, $tag){

    //if called from the 'my_primary_shortcode' shortcode
    if($tag == 'my_primary_shortcode'){
        return 'This is the primary shortcode'; 
    }
    //if called from the 'my_secondary_shortcode' shortcode
    else if($tag == 'my_secondary_shortcode'){
        return 'This is the secondary shortcode'; 
    }
    //default 
    else{
        return 'This is something else'; 
    }
    }
    add_shortcode('my_primary_shortcode','display_my_shortcode');
    add_shortcode('my_secondary_shortcode','display_my_shortcode');
```

My problem is, that the output of the template is still with php - the template I want to export would look like this:

```
<div class="blog_holder blog_small_image">
            <?php $counter = 0; ?>
                        <?php if(have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php
            if(get_the_category(get_the_ID()) != 'test123')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if($counter < 6){                           
                    get_template_part('blog_small_image', 'loop');
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
                            ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php if($qode_options_theme13['pagination'] != "0") : ?>
                                <?php pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages, $blog_page_range, $paged); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php else: //If no posts are present ?>
                            <div class="entry">
                                <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'qode'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
```

It should create a list of 5 blog posts of the category 'test123'. How would I include this output into a shortcode though. what would be the "return" value?

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: The return value should be whatever HTML the template you're exporting generates...

Comment: when you take a look at the code above, do you know by any chance if get_template_part is returning the raw template or does it already processed by the php processor and pure html?